# How to get a caption underneath two divs with images in them so the caption has text wrapping?

Tags: css, word-wrap

I've got an app where I'm displaying images, one large and then a series of smaller ones beside it. (so two columns essentially)  I am using object-fit:cover for the large image on left, so don't know the width of this div. The right I know the width, as I force it to a fixed width.

```
<div class="browseCardBody">
  <div class="browseCardImageLarge">
     <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/4242b5ed94.jpg">
   </div>
    <div class="browseCardSmallImages">
   <div style="width:133px">
    <div class="browseCardImageSmall">
    <!-- This main image scales to 300px high, varying width, how do get the text under it to match the width of this plus the fixed width div beside it??   -->
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/obwbqDT.jpg" />
    <img src="https://steemitimages.com/300x300/https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZ42wQdhPwjmhvkmQWbRRuCy1KWM2Ss95Njm5mGJijq6E/20170121_160538.jpg" />
    <img src="https://steemitimages.com/300x300/http://i.imgur.com/Oe9Yshv.jpg" />
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

</div>
<div>
   <div class="browseCardFooter" ng-if="story.body.length > 0">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS HERE:

```
.browseCardBody {
    display: flex;
    max-height: 300px;
}
.browseCardBottom li {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 6px;
}
.browseCardImageLarge {
    object-fit: contain;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 1;
}
.browseCardImageLarge img 
{
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover; 
}
.browseCardSmallImages {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 10;
    order: 2;
    height: 300px;
}
.browseCardImageSmall {
    object-fit: cover;
    display:inline-block;    
}
.browseCardImageSmall img {
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 133px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I need to make a text block under these two columns of images that matches the width without making the whole container wider.

My text when longer than the div, always widens the container, how do I prevent this without knowing the div width?

my jsfiddle here shows the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/tseqjc72/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the images and text in a container `div` of its own, and use `display: table-caption`.

[JSFiddle - Example](https://jsfiddle.net/28t0dzfq/)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  I tried some table-caption but never wrapped it all first so wasn't what I expected.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

wrap the entire thing in a div and give it a class "container" (name it whatever you want :p )

now style this class container with "display: table-caption;"

I think this should work.